# Perl_Function and subroutine

Tags: perl

What is Difference between Function and subroutine in perl ?
I found difference in few site, there i found Subroutine does not return value but function returns but actually Subroutine also return value .
Please let me know What is Exact difference between Function and subroutine in perl ?

Comment: They are synonyms. Not different terms

Comment: @KrishnachandraSharma Actually in some programming languages they are different.

Comment: Ok. That I didn't know. But here I meant specifically in perl.

Answer (score 1):

Generally in computer science a function is a special type of subroutine that returns a values (as opposed to being called just for its side-effects). But in Perl (as the cookbook says) we don't make that distinction.

The two words mean the same thing. They're synonyms.

Course: [Perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=567915).

Update: 
They are synonyms only because Perl returns last value of expression, evaluated in sub-block.

Comment: They are synonyms only because `Perl` returns last value of expression, evaluated in `sub-block`

Comment: Actually, they're synonyms only in that perl has no formal definition of a _function_ - only `sub`.  It has nothing to do with the return value.